# Handling screen rotation in WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-view, android-configchanges

My web app works great in Chrome which handles configuration changes (such as screen rotation) excellent. Everything is perfectly preserved.

When loading my web app into a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) in my Android app then the web app loses state on screen orientation change. It does *partially* preserve the state, i.e. it preserves the data of the `<input>` form elements, however all JavaScript variables and DOM manipulation gets lost.

I would like my WebView to behave the way Chrome does, i.e. fully preserving the state including any JavaScript variables. It should be noted that while Chrome and WebView derives from the same code base Chrome does not internally use WebView.

What happens on screen orientation change is that the Activity (and any eventual Fragments) gets destroyed then subsequently recreated. `WebView` inherits from [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) and overrides the methods [`onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/androidsure,/view/View.html#onSaveInstanceState%28%29) and  [`onRestoreInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Parcelable%29) for handling configuration changes hence it automatically saves and restores the contents of any HTML form elements as well as the back/forward navigation history state. However the state of the JavaScript variables and the DOM is not saved and restored.

### Proposed solutions

There have been a few proposed solutions. All of them non-working, only preserving partial state or in other ways suboptimal.

#### Assigning the WebView an id

`WebView` inherits from `View` which had the method [`setId`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29) which can also be declared in the layout XML file using the [`android:id`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:id) attribute in the declaration of the `<WebView>` element. This is necessary for the state to be saved and restored, however the state is only partially restored. This restores form input elements but not JavaScript variables and the state of the DOM.

#### onRetainNonConfigurationInstance and getLastNonConfigurationInstance

<s>[`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29)</s> and <s>[`getLastNonConfigurationInstance`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLastNonConfigurationInstance())</s> are **deprecated** since API level 13.

#### Forcing screen orientation

An Activity can have its screen orientation forced by setting the [`screenOrientation`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) attribute for the `<Activity>` element in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file or via the [`setRequestedOrientation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29) method. This is undesired as it breaks the expectation of screen rotation. This also only deals with the change of screen orientation and not other configuration changes.

#### Retaining the fragment instance

Does not work. Calling the method [`setRetainInstance`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) on a fragment does retain the fragment (it does not get destroyed), hence all the instance variables of the fragment are preserved, however it *does* destroy the fragment's view hence the `WebView` does gets destroyed.

#### Manually handling configuration changes

The [`configChanges`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges) attribute can be declared for an `Activity` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file as `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to handle [configuration changes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges) by preventing them. This works, it prevents the activity from getting destroyed hence the `WebView` and its contents is fully preserved. However this has been discouraged and is said to be used only as a last resort solution  as it may cause the app to break in subtle ways and get buggy. The method [`onConfigurationChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) gets called when the `configChanges` attribute is set.

#### MutableContextWrapper

I heard [`MutableContextWrapper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/MutableContextWrapper.html) can be used, but I haven't evaluated this approach.

#### saveState() and restoreState()

`WebView` have the methods [`saveState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [`restoreState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#restoreState%28android.os.Bundle%29). Note according to the documentation the `saveState` method no longer stores the display data for the WebView whatever that means. Either way these methods do not seem to fully preserve the state of the WebView.

#### WebViewFragment

The [`WebViewFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewFragment.html) is just a convenience fragment that wraps `WebView` for you so can easily get going with less boilerplate code, much like the `ListFragment`. It does not do any additional state preserving to fully preserve the state.

This class was deprecated in API level 28.

## Question

Is there any real solution to the problem of `WebView` getting destroyed and losing its state upon configuration changes? (such as screen rotation)

A solution that *fully* preserves all the state including JavaScript variables and DOM manipulation. A solution that is clean and not built on hacks or deprecated methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After researching and trying out different approaches I have discovered what I have come to believe is the optimal solution.

It uses [`setRetainInstance`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) to retain the fragment instance along with [`addView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) and [`removeView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29) in the [`onCreateView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView%28android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle%29) and [`onDestroyView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onDestroyView%28%29) methods to prevent the `WebView` from getting destroyed.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT = "webView";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WebViewFragment fragment = (WebViewFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new WebViewFragment();
        }

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, fragment, TAG_FRAGMENT).commit();
    }
}
```

WebViewFragment.java

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {
    private WebView mWebView;

    public WebViewFragment() {
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview, container, false);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        if (mWebView == null) {
            mWebView = new WebView(getActivity());
            setupWebView();
        }
        layout.removeAllViews();
        layout.addView(mWebView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (getRetainInstance() && mWebView.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ((ViewGroup) mWebView.getParent()).removeView(mWebView);
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    private void setupWebView() {
        mWebView.loadUrl("https:///www.example.com/");
    }
}
```

Comment: good summary of this issue. ran into it again as the app i'm working on moves back to embedded web views.

Comment: Retaining `new WebView(getActivity())` will leak the Activity context on configuration changes (because the WebView still holds a reference to the initial Activity). Also the WebView might crash when certain form elements (like a drop down list) are opened after a configuration change.

Comment: Can we use new WebView(applicationContext) for this? Also, setRetainInstance is deprecated. Can we use ViewModel to hold WebView?

Comment: @Jonas Good question. I don't know, I haven't done Android programming for years, if you find out, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

the following manifest code declares an activity that handles both the screen orientation change and keyboard availability change:
this code:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
```

becomes :

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

here you only add: screenSize, then it works fine.

reference:  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject

Answer (score 1):

Simple thing you could do is something like:

```
WebView webView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview, container, false);

    webView = v.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    } else {
        loadUrl();
    }
    return v;
}

private void loadUrl(){
    webView.loadUrl("someUrlYouWant");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    webView.saveState(outState);
}
```

**NOTE:** Did not try this code just wrote it but think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you re-render the whole thing again. I searched a while and I couldn't find a clean ready made solution. Everything out there states that you let the webpage re-render on orientation change.

But if you really need to persist your JS variables, you could imitate what `saveState` and `restoreState` did. What these methods ideally do is save and restore stuff in `WebView` using the activity's `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` respectively. These methods don't do the stuff they did because of potential memory leaks.

So, all you need to do is create your own webview (`MyWebView extends WebView`). In this have two methods: `saveVariableState()` and `restoreVariableState()`. In your `saveVariableState()` just save every variable you want in a bundle and return it ( `public Bundle saveVariableState(){}`). Now in the `onSaveInstanceState()` of the `Activity`, call `MyWebView.saveVariableState` and save the bundle it returns. Once the orientation changes, you fetch the bundle from `onRestoreInstanceState` or `onCreate` and pass it to the `MyWebView` via the constructor or `restoreVariableState`.

This is not a hack, but the normal way to save stuff of data's of other views. In case of `WebView`, instead of saving data of the view, you are going to save JS variables.

Comment: This would work for one or two variables in the global namespace, but not for created objects with modified private variables that you can't reach from the outside and DOM manipulation.